# How would a human/floral humanoid offspring look?

Tags: biology, humans, genetics, humanoid, creature-design

I’m trying to figure out what the appearance of a human and a floral humanoid offspring would look like. The floral humanoids have humanlike bodies with petal hair and “unnatural” skin color (which usually a couple shades lighter of their petal color).

We know children inherit half of their parents’ DNA. Let’s take a (white/black) biracial child for an example. The child usually has light brown skin, brown hair, and brown eyes but they can have blonde or black hair, blue/green eyes, and paler or darker skin.

If the biracial child had a child with a white person, the child would be 3/4 white and 1/4 black. The child could look more white or biracial (considering genetics isn’t the same for everyone).

I know genetics go deeper than that but I just want to provide a basic example (I’m not much a geneticist so don’t expect a complex scientific post from me lol).

The floral humanoids have flower pigments for their petals and skin color. I don’t think it can mix with human pigment and it’s not possible for genetics to come up with new pigments. It could be possible that flower pigment can transfer over to the hair or skin or maybe it could even combine with human pigment.

I’m not sure about the hair. It has to be either human, petal, or both. Of course there can’t be a mixture because it wouldn’t make any sense.

(Fun Fact: There was a human-pig hybrid. No joke. I wonder how it would’ve turned out?)

I thought about humans and floral humanoids unable to produce offspring due to genetic incompatibility.

Any ideas?

Comment: Floral is not a species, it's just a generic term to indicate anything with flowers, from a cherry tree to an amorphophallus titatum

Comment: Yeah I don’t know why I put that there but I’m glad I removed it. Well the tag.

Comment: You're better/easier off mutating humans to have these traits. Reproductive compatibility between a plant and a mammal is going to be non-existent at best.

Comment: If you insist on some sort of mingling of the kingdoms I'd suggest rather some sort of symbioses or parasitism. Humans reproduce as usual, plants reproduce as usual, but part of the life cycle of the plant is for it to find a a human to burrow into the skin and head of, causing leaves/petals and green under/over the skin.

Comment: The metabolisms are too far away to lead to a viable hybrid - the liver products will be toxic for the plants and the cellulose that the plant side is geared to use for its "body" construction will create troubles for the animal side.

Comment: Human x Flowering plant? I cannot but think the result will be something like this: https://w.notrecinema.com/images/filmsi/la-mouche-2_76428_37013.jpg

Comment: I can’t reply to every comment because the last time I did that it was too long but I though about human mutation as a evolutionary thing. A human eats a special kind of plant and gain flower/plank like traits. I’ve seen that image and I was like what the!

Comment: Fun Fact: There was never a human-pig hybrid, hybrid means something very specific in biology & neither inserting the DNA from a pig into a hollowed out human egg cell nor mashing two early stage blastocysts together to create a chimera count as a hybrid, neither does injecting a few cells from one organism into a developing embryo of another organism, a hybrid means the egg of one species has been fertilised by the sperm of another & human egg cells can't be penetrated by anything other than our nearest relatives the apes, a fun fact that's a real fact: we know this from actual experiments.

Comment: Further fun facts: ^ of the three methods detailed above (that are not hybrids) only one could produce anything that would look like & be anything other than a perfectly normal human or pig, mashing two early stage blastocysts together would be that one .. inject a pigs nuclear DNA into a human egg cell & you'll just get a pig (other way around & you just get a human), inject a few cells from another animal into an embryo of another & they just 'go native' & take their developmental cues from the organism they're in & you'll get a perfectly normal animal of the embryo's species.

Comment: *"mashing two early stage blastocysts together would be that one"* if the two blastocysts are roughly the same stage of development (same size & number of cells) they'll produce a single organism likely with wildly differing bits depending on where the cells of each end up distributed, you'll likely get a random mix of human & pig limbs & body sections rather than any coherent blending of the forms of the two species expected with hybrids, like a kids flip books where you choose different feet legs body & head.

Comment: If what you're thinking of involved CRSPR that's not a hybrid either & nothing done with it to date will produce any change to the organisms morphology, splicing in a DNA segment to produce a protein or whatever isn't making a hybrid & won't effect anything else in the organism.

Comment: @Pelinore Thanks for clarifying and debunking the human-pig hybrid. Honestly, I have some doubts about the legitimacy of a “human-pig” hybrid. I figured it wouldn’t turn out like how I would’ve imagined. A human cell isn’t a sperm (vice versa). I wish people would stop doing these kind of experiments because they don’t know what they’re getting themselves into.

Comment: @Sydni I spent a lot of time reading up on all this a few years back when I was interested in the possibility for transplant organs of introducing a few cells from a donor species into the patient while still an embryo so it can receive organs from them in later life without tissue rejection (never going to happen for 'morale' & 'ethical' reasons but would work), I became very 'annoyed' in that time with media & others misuse of the word hybrid when talking about much of this stuff because its understood (& actual) meaning is so misleading to those they're 'informing', sorry for the rant :)

Answer (score 4):

## Anything you want.

Human and plants are massively genetically different and are utterly incompatible for breeding. As such, radical genetic engineering or magic or a wildly different evolutionary chain is needed.

As such, you can have whatever combination you want. You're not bound by normal biology. You can swap pigments, have them look like whatever, and adjust the form according to your whims.

Comment: Yeah I shouldn’t limit my imagination. They can be anything!

Comment: THis. When you are combining HUman and PLANT, you have not only thrown out the rulebook, you have ground it to confetti, mulched it in a deep peat bog, and set it on fire.  As you are already disregarding *all* the rules of biology, and quite a few of physics, you might as well go Full Monty and approach it as pure fantasy.

Comment: Haha true. I was planning it to be pure fantasy.

Comment: If it's fantasy you can do whatever. Say they blended their magical essences or something and have whatever you like best, or whatever looks best when you google flower people.

Answer (score 3):

### It depends.

What's the full appearance of the floral race? How human looking are they? If the petals are the only nonhuman trait we could assume their offspring wouldn't be that different. If they are more plant-like with more alien bodies then it's a different story. In genetics it's a law that two species that aren't closely related can't reproduce. For that you have two choices: first they are basically human with a few different genes and second they are xenophiles that can reproduce with anything.

**When thinking about hybrids try to look at tigons and ligers for reference.**

A [tigon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigon) is the offspring of a male tiger and female lion. However a [liger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liger) is an interesting case of genetics. They are the offspring of a male lion and female tiger. You'll notice that they are huge compared to either species. This is the result of a gene present in lion males that usually is inhibited by a gene in females. However tigers lack this system and ligers grow to huge as a result.

**Floral and human hybrids might have variations.**

- Human mother and Floral father could lead to a mostly human child with petal hair and a slightly more human colour. We are sort of pink, yellow or brown.
- Floral mother and human father could lead to a mostly floral child with an alien looking body but human hair for example.

**Think about what florals have that we lack and vice versa.**

Florals may have genes that decide how large their petals grow. A hybrid may have oversized petals  as a sign of their mixed heritage.

Comment: Those ideas are pretty interesting! I have to take notes but the liger example is cool.

Answer (score 1):

### Colour

Their skin tone should feature both parent's pigments at half intensity. However, this will not mean a mixture of both parent's skin tones; the actual mixture will appear more human-like with darker skin tones. They will vary between half-and-half with a dark-skinned human parent to a lighter version of the floral parent with a pale-skinned human parent

### Hair/Petals

There's no given reason can't have both hair and petals. They could easily both coexist together on the head. In this state, both structures will probably be thinner or less extensive than in their parents. The colouration of the hair and petals will be independent, and inherited directly from the relevant parent

Comment: I had a hard time figuring out the skin tone part. It makes sense for it to be human like since the hybrid is half human. I envisioned the part petal, part hair part and I was thinking of ways of how it would be positioned on top of the head.

Answer (score 1):

**They are normal humans.**

This is because the floral colored humans are genetically engineered post conception, starting from normal human stock.  Here is the scheme, from a different question.

[Practical reason for genetically engineering exotic skin colors in humans?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/169552/practical-reason-for-genetically-engineering-exotic-skin-colors-in-humans/169597#169597)

Your floral humans start as fertilized human zygotes.  Genetically engineered neural crest cells are added at the correct embryonic stage, and these migrate to take up their roles as melanocytes.  Cells destined to become hair bearing epithelia are also added to produce the petal effect.  These engineered cells have various pigments added to produce the floral colors desired.

The engineered human has the spectacular floral look you request but the base genome is that of a normal human as are the gametes.  Engineering is confined to particular somatic cells.  When a floral human reproduces with a human, the offspring is human.

This protects the delicate deep workings of the organism from being disrupted by introduced genes, which are confined to somatic stem cells.  Occasionally there are disruptions, and occasionally old floral humanoids start reverting to their "rootstock" and lose their petals and pigments with age.

The fact that the floral people do not breed true also protects the commercial enterprise producing and selling them, because otherwise anyone with access to some flower people (like the flower people themselves) could breed their own flower people and flood the market or at least make them so common that prices drop.  It is the same principle as improved seeds that do not breed true.  That preserves the market for improved seeds.

Comment: Wow, that’s actually a very interesting idea! I haven’t really though about the scientific aspect of the floral humanoids but I want to look at your idea and see what I can do with it.